# How to get all id from documents in a collection and update only one boolean field?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Android studio and I would like to update a boolean from CloudFirestore from specific query, I want to update only the documents from collection that have true. Put them again to false.

Till now I have this, and I don't know why doesn't work. Anyone can help? thanks!!

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
        .build();
fStore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
fStore.collection("users/" + userID + "/Exercicis" ).whereEqualTo("fet", true)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            String data = "";

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                Exercicis exercicis = documentSnapshot.toObject(Exercicis.class);
                                exercicis.setDocumentid(documentSnapshot.getId());

                                String documentId = exercicis.getDocumentid();

                                DocumentReference exercicisusuari = fStore.document("users/" + userID + "/Exercicis/" + documentId);
                                exercicisusuari.update("fet", false);
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
```

I add the Exercicis class and the structure of my database.

[image]

```
public class Exercicis {

    private String documentid, nom, codi, info, temps,fotoperfil, fotoexercici;
    private boolean fet;

    public String getDocumentid() {
        return documentid;
    }

    public void setDocumentid(String documentid) {
        this.documentid = documentid;
    }

    public Exercicis() {
    }

    public Exercicis(String nom, String codi, String info, String temps, Boolean fet, String fotoperfil, String fotoexercici) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.codi = codi;
        this.info = info;
        this.temps = temps;
        this.fet = fet;
        this.fotoperfil = fotoperfil;
        this.fotoexercici = fotoexercici;

    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getCodi() {
        return codi;
    }

    public void setCodi(String codi) {
        this.codi = codi;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getTemps() {
        return temps;
    }

    public void setTemps(String temps) {
        this.temps = temps;
    }

    public boolean getFet() {return fet; }

    public void setFet(boolean fet) {this.fet = fet;}

    public String getFotoperfil() {return fotoperfil;}

    public void setFotoperfil(String fotoperfil) {this.fotoperfil = fotoperfil;}

    public String getFotoexercici() {return fotoexercici;}

    public void setFotoexercici(String fotoexercici) {this.fotoexercici = fotoexercici;}
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your `Exercicis` class.

Comment: Add a complete listener to this line of code `exercicisusuari.update("fet", false);`. Do you get any message?

Comment: I tried but no message in console.
```exercicisusuari.update("fet", false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        Log.d(TAG,"Updated...");
                                    }
                                });```

Comment: Is your `onSuccess` even triggered?

Comment: No, I didn't, how I do that? thanks

Comment: That's because you don't have an internet connection.

Comment: I have not any onSucces, how I can add to my code?